# Rails JSON API testing POST request with PARAMS in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, testing, rspec

This is a problem that has been bothering me for some time. I am building an API function that should receive data in json and response in json. My controller tests run fine(Since I abstract that the data gets there already decode from JSON and only the answer needs to be interpreted ).

I Also know that the function runs fine since I have used curl to test it with JSON arguments and it works perfectly. 
(ex: curl -i --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"test":{"email":"andreo@benjamin.dk"}}' )

But obviously I would like to write request(feature) tests to test this automatically and the way I see it they should work exactly like curl, i.e., hit my service like it was an external call. That means that I would like to pass the arguments in JSON and receive an answer. I am pretty lost since all the examples I can see people treat arguments as it was already decoded.

My question is: I am following a wrong premise in wanting to send the arguments and request as a JSON one since i will be testing that rails works, because this is its responsibility? But I would like to see how robust my code his to wrong arguments and would like to try with JSON.

something of this type:

```
it "should return an error if there is no correct email" do
    params = {:subscription => {:email => "andre"}}

    post "/magazine_subscriptions", { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json", 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'RAW_POST_DATA' => params.to_json }
end
```

Do you know how this is possible? and please let me know if you think I am testing it wrong.

all the best,

Andre

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found my answer on a post here([RSpec request test merges hashes in array in POST JSON params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337609/rspec-request-test-merges-hashes-in-array-in-post-json-params)), I think what I was doing wrong concerned the arguments to the request.

so this worked:

```
it "should return an error if there is no correct email" do
    params = {:subscription => {:email => "andre"}}

    post "/magazine_subscriptions", params.to_json, {'ACCEPT' => "application/json", 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'}
end
```

Comment: For brevity, write it as `post '/magazine_subscriptions', params.to_json, format: :json`.

Comment: @user664833 that's more elegant

Comment: I don't think that .to_json is necessary if you are already formatting it as a json object.  I think it should be  `post '/magazine_subscriptions', params, format: :json`

Comment: Or `post "/magazine_subscriptions.json", params`

Comment: In minitest, Rails 6.0.4.7, format: :json didn't work. I had to use `post "url", as: :json, params: {}`

Answer (score 1):

```
describe '#create' do 
  let(:email) {'andre'}
  let(:attrs) {{email: email}}
  let(:params) {{format: :json, subscription: attrs}}

  it "should return an error if there is no correct email" do
    post "/magazine_subscriptions", params
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a hard time finding an example for recent versions of rails. `post "/magazine_subscriptions", subscription: subscription_params, format: :json` was the key for me. No `to_json` necessary.