# Value not getting passed to controller after post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a simple post call using ajax, the form contains a language identifier, an i18n key, and a string translation value.

I have my route set up as follows:

```
post '/translate/' => 'pages#translate'
```

For test purposes, in `PagesController::translate` I am simply calling:

```
render json: params
```

In my coffee script I am using the following code:

```
console.log $form.serialize()
$.post $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(),
    (json) ->
        console.log json
        return
, 'json'
```

And I'm using the following HAML to output the form:

```
%div#translation-control
    = form_tag '/translate/', :method => "post" do
        = hidden_field_tag :translationlang, I18n.locale
        = select_tag :translationkey, options_for_select(get_all_translations().invert())
        = text_area_tag(:translationvalue, '', :rows => '1')
        = button_tag "Add"
```

In my log I see:

```
translationlang=en&translationkey=home.welcome&translationvalue=Welcome+to+this+site
Object {
    action: "translate"
    controller: "pages"
    translationlang: "en"
}
```

I have tried several different methods of setting up my route, including:

```
post '/translate/:translationlang/:translationkey/:translationvalue' => 'pages#translate'

match '/translate/:translationlang/:translationkey/:translationvalue' => 'pages#translate', 
:constraints => { :translationkey => /[\w\_\-\.]+/, :translationvalue => /.*/ },
via: [:post]
```

But nothing seems to work. Why are `translationkey` and `translationvalue` not getting passed to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was going to write a comment, but this will be clearer:

---

**.to_json**

Have you tried [`.to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)? 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683336/rails-json-api-testing-post-request-with-params-in-json) seems to be very receptive of the idea:

```
render json: params.to_json
```

Failing that, have you considered just testing static text:

```
render "hello".to_json ?
```

---

**Controller**

Are you sure you're getting the right data / params sent to your controller? Some good feedback would be your log of the requests

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the request and the parameters were not getting passed, jQuery seemed to be messing up the serialize method somehow. Not quite sure what happened but called serialize() before the $.post method (instead of passing it directly in) and the right parameters got through.